# External CSS property interfering with struts 2 radio button layout

Tags: css, struts2

I am using my own style sheet in a `.jsp` with the following rule (which is not working as I intended):

```
label {
  display: block;
}
```

The same CSS will be used by many `jsp`s. My Application is configured with `struts.ui.theme=simple`.

The following `s:radio` displays radio buttons and their labels vertically:

```
<s:radio name="allowPartial"   list="#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}"/>

*

Yes

*

No
```

When I remove the following CSS rule:

```
label {
  display: block;
}
```

It displays as I intend it (inline):

```
* Yes * No
```

How do I fix this at the tag level without changing the CSS file since it is being used by other `jsp`s?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using cssClass

Add an class to the `s:radio`, like `cssClass="example"`, then create a new CSS entry:

```
.example label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will have greater specificity, and override the `label` selector. You said your description that you do not want to modify the stylesheet, so I give you another option.

#### Using cssStyle

The uglier (and simpler) way, is using the `cssStyle="display: inline-block;"` in the `s:radio` tag directly.

PS: If this does not work, please add a comment, and show the generated HTML, as it would help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I just edited the question to show clearer intent (I hope!). This is probably the best/most straightforward answer. Using a `cssClass` is preferred to inlining styles.